# Can you help me when I select Desc in dropdown list google sheet I want the value become unique number

Tags: validation, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have a google Spreadsheet.

- Column A = Unique number,
- Column B = Desc

In column C, I use data validation from column B. I want when I select 1 value the result in column C should be column A. I tried include image to become more clear. Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o40K4.png]

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look into [StackOverflow: How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to get a prompt response you can summarize the title and what's actually your expected code behavior. It's helpful for the community. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(D3, {B:B, A:A}, 2, 0))
```

or:

```
=IFNA(FILTER(B:B, A:A=D3))
```